# Laravel Echo / Socket.io keeping connection alive after sleep

Tags: laravel, vue.js, redis, socket.io, laravel-echo

I'm using `laravel echo server` + `Redis` on the back-end (with default configs) and `laravel-echo` with `socket.io-client` on Vue front-end.

Here is my use case:
Whenever a new order is submitted, I use `laravel-echo` to update a list of orders with a newly submitted one.

Everything works fine as long as the connected device (i.e. iPhone) is awake.

My problem is with cases when new orders are submitted while the device is asleep. After waking up the device, the list of orders is not updated (if new orders are submitted after waking up the device - the list is updated as it should).

How do I update the list with new orders that was submitted **while** the device was asleep?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got so far. Eager to see if there is a better idea:

```
export default {
  async beforeMount () {
    await this.updateOrders()

    const vm = this
    Echo.channel('update-orders-channel')
      .listen('NewOrderEvent', async (e) => {
        await vm.updateOrders(e)
      })

    Echo.connector.socket.on('reconnecting', async () => {
      await vm.updateOrders()
    })
  }
}
```